# Division Algorithm: Uniqueness of quotient and remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

The Division Algorithm states that given an integer $a$ and $b$ it is always possible to find unique integers $q$ and $r$ so that $a = bq+r$ and $0\le r <b$

Now having proved the existence of $q$ and $r$ using Well Ordering principle, can't we use it to prove their uniqueness too?

I mean let we have a set $S=\{a-bx \ | \ x\in Z^+ \text{ and } a-bx \ge0\}$. If we say that $r = a-bq$ is least element of $S$, doesn't that testify its uniqueness? There can be only one least element? Sorry if my logic is flawed, the text I referred proved it in another manner.

Comment: You must show that if $b'$ and $r'$ satisfy the conditions, then $b=b'$ and $r=r'$.  Perhaps $r'$ isn't the least element of $S$.  You're right that some thing is unique, but the unique smallest element of $S$ isn't the same as the uniqueness of the division algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelBurr If we let $r = a - bq$ and say that any variation on $q$ (i mean $r' = a - b(q+k), k \in Z$) would cause $r'$ to either be not in $S$ or be greater than $b$?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really shown that there can't be another q and r such that the equality holds. You've just shown basically the existence again.